# Cassandra Alter Column type from Timestamp to Date

Tags: date, datetime, cassandra

Is there any way to alter the Cassandra column from timestamp to date without data lost? For example '2021-02-25 20:30:00+0000' to '2021-02-25'

If not, what is the easiest way to migrate this column(timestamp) to the new column(date)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to change a type of the existing column, so you need to add a new column with correct data type, and perform migration.  Migration could be done via Spark + [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/) - it could be most flexible solution, and even could be done via single node machine with Spark running in the local master mode (default).  Code could look something like this (try on test data first):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
options = { "table": "tbl", "keyspace": "ks"}
spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**options).load()\
  .select("pk_col1", "pk_col2", F.col("timestamp_col").cast("date").alias("new_name"))\
  .write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(**options).save()
```

P.S. you can use [DSBulk](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html), for example, but you need to have enough space to offload the data (although you need only primary key column + your timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Alex Ott's answer, there are validations done in Cassandra that prevents changing the data type of a column. The reason is that SSTables (Cassandra data files) are immutable -- once they are written to disk, they are never modified/edited/updated. They can only be compacted to new SSTables.

Some try to get around it by dropping the column from the table then adding it back in with a new data type. Unlike traditional RDBMS, the existing data in the SSTables don't get updated so if you tried to read the old data, you'll get a `CorruptSSTableException` because the CQL type of the data on disk won't match that of the schema.

For this reason, it is no longer possible to drop/recreate columns with the same name ([CASSANDRA-14948](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14948)). If you're interested, I've explained it in a bit more detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/8018/. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToDate to change it. For example: Table Email has column Date with format: 2001-08-29 13:03:35.000000+0000.

```
Select Date, ToDate(Date) as Convert from keyspace.Email:

date | convert ---------------------------------+------------ 2001-08-29 13:03:35.000000+0000 | 2001-08-29
```